# Removing unique elements from list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to remove unique elements from a list in Prolog.

Output should look something like:

```
?- rem_Uniq([3,3,1,7,a,c,c],D).
D = [3, c].
```

Here is my current code.

```
rem_Uniq(L1,L2).
rem_Uniq([L1|RL1], [L1|D]) :-
    member(L1,RL1),
    rem_Uniq(RL1,D).
rem_Uniq([L1|RL1], D) :-
    remove(L1[L1|RL1], O),
    rem_Uniq(O, D).
```

Currently it just returns true no matter what I do (whether I enter I list containing unique variables or not).

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is the set of elements of the list which appears only one time.

In Prolog **"an element which appears only one time in a list"** can be translate by

```
select(X, L, L_X),
\+member(X, L_X)
```

In Prolog exist predicates that collect element with a certain property **setof/3** and **bagof/3**.

bagof collect all the elements, setof keeps only one element.
So you can write

```
rem_uniq(In, Out) :-
    setof(X, In_X^(select(X, In, In_X),\+member(X, In_X)), Out).
```

**[EDIT]**

Now we want only elements that are duplicated in a list. If I remove one of these elements of the list, it will  remain other elements of the same value in the list so it can be translated in Prolog by

```
select(X, In, In_X),
member(X, In_X)
```

(we say that **select(X, In, In_X),member(X, In_X)** succeed).
Now the code can be written

```
rem_uniq(In, Out) :-
    setof(X, In_X^(select(X, In, In_X),member(X, In_X)), Out).
```

For example

```
?- rem_uniq([3,3,1,7,a,c,c],D).
D = [3,c].
```

Note that setof will fail if there no elements available

```
 ?- rem_uniq([3,1,7,a,c],D).
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer joel76, however It only keeps unique elements... not elements that have been duplicated.

How would I change it? Just a little pointer please, not necessarily the code for how to do it... I want to try and work it out. I'm sorry btw, I just don't understand prolog

Comment: How would you translate in Prolog  "an element is duplicated in a list" ? There is not a lot of change to do in my code to translate. (select remove the element X of the list).

Comment: sadly I could not work this out.

I want to say thanks for your help anyway as I understand the problem, I started going through all of the predicates in prolog and for the first time actually began to understand what they actually do.

I probably won't be submitting correct answers for my homework, however this is the closest I have come to understanding how prolog actually works based on your answer so I'll call that a win... kinda?

thanks anyway :). Maybe some more practise down the line will help me get it.

Comment: @TheLeftRight I made an edit to my answer to solve your problem

Comment: Now that I see it, I don't understand how I couldn't work that out...It seems so simple now it's put like that...


Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first problem is your first clause:

```
rem_Uniq(L1,L2).
```

This literally says "Any two things are rem_Uniq to each other." This is what's giving rise to always getting true with no unifications. You probably meant this:

```
rem_Uniq([], []).
```

Your second problem is that this is not valid syntax:

```
 remove(L1[L1|RL1], O),
```

Specifically, `L1[L1|RL1]`, I am unclear what you meant there. I think you meant this `delete(L1, [L1|RL1], O)`.

Now, algorithmically, I think you're a little confused. In clause #2, you prepend L1 to D in the result, which is to say, after knowing that L1 *is* present in RL1 and using the recursive call to remove it from D. But then in clause #3, you just remove it from [L1|RL1] to make O, which you then remove uniques from.

Each clause of a recursive predicate should represent a case you have to worry about. I don't really see what these clauses mean. The first one should be, in case where the list is empty. The second one should be the case where the list is not empty. What you seem to be trying to do here is something like, in the case where the list is not empty and contains the head element, and the case where it is not empty and does not contain the head element, but the distinction between having or not having that element is (or ought to be) meaningless to your library routine. In other words, `delete/3` in one non-empty recursive case should be totally sufficient for this problem:

```
rem_uniq([], []).
rem_uniq([X|Xs], [X|UniqueXs]) :- 
  delete(X, Xs, XsWithoutX),
  rem_uniq(XsWithoutX, UniqueXs).
```

So, I think you have a little confusion about when and why you should have multiple clauses, and I think your choice of variable names may have made life harder on yourself. But that's just my guess.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I am currently at work but will play with this when I get home. I very much appreciate your in depth answer and explanation

Comment: Hi Daniel, 

I have been playing a little with this code and it now returns false regardless of whether there is a duplicate in the list or not? Am I doing something wrong?